# How to get search engines to index pages containing dynamic content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index, dynamic

Is there a good way to get dynamic content indexed?

e.g: When I search query "restaurants in norway" in Google, I see a link of `www.europages.com/directory/pages/...` (not relevant URL), but it is full of relevant content (a restaurants list).  This content is fully dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you want to index search results. If I'm right, it's against Google's guidelines, [according to Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/).

I recommend you to only index valuable content and not auto generated pages.

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't get my answer on the above link :(

Answer (score 2):

Search engine spiders can't tell what content is dynamic and what content it static.  When you serve a page to them, they will index whatever content is on that page, be it dynamic or static.

To be able to find the pages with the dynamic content, you must link to those pages from somewhere else on the site.  The "restaurants in norway" page from your example is linked from other pages on the europages.com site.

Comment: thanks I think this clears it up for me, So if I have a list of doctors and want google to index it I just give it a link in some part of my website. But I wonder. This list of doctors is populated with content from a database, So I should make the call and retrieve info BEFORE I render the webpage in clientside, (so make call to DB on backend/server)?

Comment: It is easier for good SEO to do the database call on the server and populate the page with the data server side.   You can use client methods such as AJAX, but SEO is not guaranteed.